# How to add custom attribtue in the ProductInterface of GraphQL response?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento2.4, graphql, pwa-studio

I have lots of custom attributes created for product and i want to include those in the ProductInterface response when called through GraphQl, is there any way for me to add those ? or do i need to create resolver for each attribute and manually add those into the schema.graphqls ?